# Java: Match with Regex and replace every character

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a string, for ex:

```
There exists a word *random*.
```

`random` will be a random word.
How can I use a regular expression to replace every character of `random` with `*` and have this result:

```
There exists a word ********.
```

So the `*` replaces every character, in this case 6 characters.
Notice that I am after to replace only the word `random`, not the surroundings `*`.
So far I have:

```
str.replaceAll("(\\*)[^.]*(\\*)", "\\*");
```

But it replaces `*random*` with `*`, instead of the desired `********` (total of 8).
Any help, really appreciated...

Comment: You always want to replace word after "There exists a word"?

Comment: you want to do masking of a word between **. Am i right?

Comment: @Achintya Jha, Even the whole sentence may be different, so basically I want to replace the word wrapped in *.

Comment: @Real, I don't know what masking means. Should I search for it?

Comment: @MikeSpy.. Can you have multiple words like that? or just 1?

Comment: I thank all of you for your fast answers and effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### If you have just a single word like that: -

As far as current example is concerned, if you are having just a single word like that, then you can save yourself from regex, by using some `String` class methods: -

```
String str = "There exists a word *random*.";

int index1 = str.indexOf("*");
int index2 = str.indexOf("*", index1 + 1);

int length = index2 - index1 - 1;   // Get length of `random`

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

// Append part till start of "random"
builder.append(str.substring(0, index1 + 1));

// Append * of length "random".length()
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    builder.append("*");
}

// Append part after "random"
builder.append(str.substring(index2));

str = builder.toString();
```

---

### If you can have multiple words like that: -

For that, here's a regex solution (This is where it starts getting a little complex): -

```
String str = "There exists a word *random*.";
str = str.replaceAll("(?<! ).(?!([^*]*[*][^*]*[*])*[^*]*$)", "*");
System.out.println(str);
```

The above pattern replaces all the characters that is not followed by `string containing even numbers of *` till the end, with a `*`.

Whichever is appropriate for you, you can use.

I'll add an explanation of the above regex: -

```
(?<! )       // Not preceded by a space - To avoid replacing first `*`
.            // Match any character
(?!          // Not Followed by (Following pattern matches any string containing even number of stars. Hence negative look-ahead
    [^*]*    // 0 or more Non-Star character
    [*]      // A single `star`
    [^*]*    // 0 or more Non-star character
    [*]      // A single `star`
)*           // 0 or more repetition of the previous pattern.
[^*]*$       // 0 or more non-star character till the end.
```

Now the above pattern will match only those words, which are `inside a pair of stars`. Provided *you don't have any unbalanced `stars`*.

Comment: I agree with Rohit..
Regex is used for patterns but what you are searching for is a definite thing.

Comment: Wow! That was amazing! I am trying for almost 2 hours to find a regex, with no luck at all! And you Robit Jain, came up with the regex in 5 minutes!

Comment: @Rohit Jain: Great answer +1 for you.

Comment: @MikeSpy.. haha :) Well, one day you will also make regex like that in 5 minutes. It's just a matter of experience, and nothing else. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer and the explanation provided. I believe this is a very good reference, as I didn't find anything online.

Comment: Hi @Rohit Jain I just want request you to help me understanding above regular expression. I want to understand above regular expression.

Comment: @RohitJain, I hope so! But I don't believe so :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Real.. I have already added an explanation, in the best way I can. Still, if you have any issue, you can ask. Please be specific, what you don't understand.

Comment: @MikeSpy.. Well, stop everything, but don't stop believing yourself.

Comment: I want to discuss .(?=[^*]*[*][^*]*$) regular expression. means how it matches to a string in detail. So that i can also write regular expression like you.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the word between `*` and do a replaceAll characters with `*` on it.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

String txt = "There exists a word *random*.";
// extract the word
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[*](.*?)[*]").matcher(txt);
if (m.find()) {
    // group(0): *random*
    // group(1): random
    System.out.println("->> " + m.group(0));
    txt = txt.replace(m.group(0), m.group(1).replaceAll(".", "*"));
}
System.out.println("-> " + txt);
```

You can see it on ideone: http://ideone.com/VZ7uMT

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String s = "There exists a word *random*.";
    s = s.replaceAll("\\*.+\\*", s.replaceAll(".*(\\*.+\\*).*", "$1").replaceAll(".", "*"));
    System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
There exists a word ********.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "There exists a word *random*.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\*)[^.]*(\\*)");

    java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    String s = "";
    if (m.find())
        s = m.group();

    int index = str.indexOf(s);
    String copy = str;
    str = str.substring(0, index);

    for (int i = index; i < index + s.length(); i++) {
        str = str + "*";
    }
    str = str + copy.substring(index + s.length(), copy.length());

    System.out.println(str);

}
```